# Please Help Clear the Tag Synonym Queue

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The [tag synonym approval queue](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested) is not part of the regular review queues. In fact, it's a bit hard to find. There are currently five synonym suggestions dating from 2017 (yeah, *five years ago*) waiting for approval.

Please take a moment to visit the above link and cast your vote for the synonyms.

My request is specifically on behalf of the discussion concerning the conversion of [reality-check](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check) to [internal-consistency](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internal-consistency) and the subsequent assignment of [reality-check](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check) as a synonym to [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based). You can read more about that at [If we can't burn the "reality check" tag, can we rename it?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9790/40609).

This post will be deleted once the synonym queue has been cleared. *Thank you!*

---

**EDIT:** While I greatly appreciate dealing with the one synonym required to resolve the [reality-check](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check) problem, can't we get the other four out of the way, too? Isn't there a badge or something for participating in the synonym queue?

Comment: Ouchie, found it without using your link, they couldn't have hidden it better. Well, perhaps if it was only in one of the link at the bottom...

Comment: Why not convert Reality-Check to Internal-Consistency, and then assign Reality-Check as a synonym for Internal-Consistency. Would it not be easier to do that than try to redefine the tag? For me, RC has always *meant* internal consistency --- does this phenomenon "fit" with a world that has A, B, C & D properties kind of thing.

Comment: @elemtilas The entire problem is that people who didn't read the tag wikis treated [tag:reality-check] as a synonym of [tag:science-based], which is why we made it a synonym of that tag. We old farts may need to realign our thinking a bit, but the new kids can keep on not reading the wikis and treat [tag:reality-check] as "is this realistic?" rather than "does this conform to my rules?"

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh... I shheeee. You've got too much high-score answers @JBH :p. I can't see nor vote for other synonym proposals, because [I've got no answer with +5 votes for these](https://imgur.com/a/DDotWFY). That's pretty constraining if tags only have 3 or 4 questions...

Comment: @Tortliena Oh good grief... I'd completely forgotten about that restriction. No wonder the stupid queue isn't clearing. (\*sigh\*) Okey-dokey! I'll stop complaining because at this point most everybody's wondering how many kinds of idiot I am. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @JBH Nah, the only thing I see is some bad game design and UI mechanics with smaller stack-exchanges and tags ^^. There are plenty of people who can vote for these tags, and well, I'm not surprised you forgot that rule, so it's not silly from your behalf .

Comment: I only saw two in the queue (anthropology and medieval Europe). What are the other three?

Comment: @elemtilas Current score [1] for [tag:arctic] => [tag:polar-region] by L.Dutch♦ on Jan 22, 2021; [1] for [tag:simulation] => [tag:virtual-reality] by Starfish Prime on Nov 14, 2019; [2] for [tag:anthropology] => [tag:culture] by JBH on Dec 26, 2018; [2] for [tag:medieval-europe] => [tag:medieval] by James on Jun 8, 2017. The fifth was [tag:reality-check] => [tag:science-based], but it's cleared. *I can't even imagine how many there really are....*

Comment: I voted against the medieval-europe synonym because I think that medieval-europe is itself a standard fantasy setting base with a relatively concrete list of tropes, whereas just medieval is way too broad to use in that same fashion, since lots of countries had periods we qualify as medieval.

Comment: @KeizerHarm That's OK. I'm neither for nor against (except for those I submitted. I'm for those I submitted). But thanks for voting!