# Please review the updated tag wikis for internal-consistency, science-fiction, science-based, and hard-science

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tag-wiki

The tag wikis for the following tags have been updated based on the results of [If we can't burn the "reality check" tag, can we rename it?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9790/40609)

- [internal-consistency](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internal-consistency)
- [science-fiction](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction)
- [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based)
- [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science)

I sincerely hope everyone agrees with me when I say I'm ***much*** happier with these four tags and the types of answers they represent. They're better scoped and harder to abuse. However, try as I might, I'm not perfect.

I would appreciate people taking the time to read the tag summaries and tag wikis. If you have questions about the tag info, please post them as comments. If you have recommendations for improvements, please post those as answers.

If you feel that something's "off" about one or more of the tags, post that as an answer, too, as it might indicate the need for an additional tag.

If you go looking for the [reality-check](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check) tag and don't find it, that's because it's been suggested to become a synonym of [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based) and is stuck in the synonym approval queue.

*And if you haven't helped [clear the synonym queue](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested), please do so now. Thanks!*

Comment: "Read the tag wiki" doesn't help if the link is named "Learn more…" ... the preview of the address is */info*... only the hover-description calls it a Tag Wiki. - "REVIEW THE WIKI BEFORE USING THIS TAG and flag your question for moderator attention once posted." - more hoops? Write a script that auto flags HS questions. Or even better, a script that puts the message if it has the tag. Other than that the other tags' descriptions suffice.

Comment: #sarcasm. The `tag-wiki` tag description : *that place no one has ever gone before except people who probably no longer needed to read it.* - Shouting at them is fine (because *you are entering hard mode*), but, "you need to *learn more* by clicking this link to another castle", which by the way is eight paragraphs long and misnomer. ? Uh, nope.

Comment: @Mazura Dude, write the scripts yourself. If you want to complain about network-wide issues, go complain on [meta.se]. I don't even know what you're talking about in your second comment. Are you actually complaining about Stack Exchange on the Worldbuilding Stack?

Comment: @JBH I'm surely missing some eyes, but I cannot see the question's header for the hard-science tag anymore, like [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/232591/where-should-i-put-the-bridge-of-a-warship). You know, the one that made this tag much more visible, like... [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/122564/would-planets-be-cubic-in-my-cuboverse) ^^. Is this a byproduct of the operation?

Comment: @Tortliena Per the tag wiki, somebody must flag the question for moderator attention and ask for the Hard Science header to be activated. It's not automatic. If it's not there, nobody flagged the mods. O'course, I looked at that first link's tag list and there be no [tag:hard-science] tag....

Comment: How can I see this one in the queue?

Comment: @elemtilas Which one? The [tag:reality-check] synonym vote? That hit its required 5 votes pretty quickly after my post, so it fell out of the queue.

Answer (score 1):

### Headers for hard-science tag should be automatically added, and flagged for removal if needed

- **That was not part of the top-voted answer of the debate**, nor its main topic.
- Since it's a very specific tag with ultra-precise goals, it has the need to be visible. It's therefore a standard, not an exception and thus should be automatically implemented.
- **Let's not overwhelm the moderators**. While those headers were not removed when changing tags as far as I remember,  removing the hard-science tag is done more rarely than choosing it in the first place. It's therefore the exception and should be treated this way.
- **It makes the tag's description shorter.** Reading the wiki is already scarsely done, having a way to shorten it will reduce the likelyhood of people [pressing the "skip" button of their gamepad](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PlayTheGameSkipTheStory).
- Did I already said to not overwhelm the moderators :p? I live to believe that repetitive tasks like these should be avoided when possible. They're not funny to do and it's statistically easier to forget or make mistakes .

Comment: This is a nice idea, but it requires a code change at the network level. It's quite literally something we have no control over. If you want to make this suggestion, it belongs on [meta.se], not here where it won't be seen by anyone at SE who can do anything about it. Frankly, I'm grateful to the moderators for coming up with a solution using the tools they have available to them. I'm also grateful that few questions get tagged [tag:hard-science].

Comment: Wait, you mean that it was manually added the whole time before? Golly log, someone needs to behead the header. Or make the task head towards the dev log.

Comment: +1. This suggestion belongs [here, *not*] on Meta Stack Exchange, [...] where it won't be seen by anyone. Get 100 UV from users here, *then* go show *this* to the three people at SE who matter. Escalate to the dev team (+2) perhaps via one of the mods here having seen this.... With no backup, a feature request on Main is a waste of time, and you only get one shot before it's a dupe. "Reading the wiki is already scarcely done" +3 - When you leave who's going to yell at all the noobs to read tag descriptions, let alone wikis. If my comments didn't make sense, here they are in extended form, +4.